# closing an IDLE window from inside the script

Tags: python, python-2.7, exit, python-idle

I have been looking around the internet and some stack overflow questions for a while now, but cannot figure this out. What I need is something that makes the IDLE shell window close. Here is what I have tried and failed with:

```
exit()
or
quit()
```

Both give me a prompt asking if I want to kill the program, which is stupid as I otherwise wouldnt use that command. If i select yes, the window closes as I want it to do but i need that to happen automaticly.

```
import sys
sys.exit()
or
raise SystemExit
```

Neither seem to be doing anything. No output and nothing happens.

```
import os
os._exit()
```

Does exit the script but instead of closing the window it restarts the shell inside.

```
let the main thread exit the script
```

Makes >>> appear and lets me use the console.

I need to be running the script in idle because of it letting me use the console for debugging. There is no way that I know of that makes it possible to access the python console if the script is running in the command line.

I am running the script on a raspberry pi 3 with raspbian jessie but I see the same behaviour on my windows 10 system.
using python 2.7.9

Comment: Do you have to use IDLE? Could you just use the python interpreter?

Comment: @Holloway as i said, the idle shell lets me use the python console while the script is running. i cannot do this if i use the console("python <scriptname>.py")

Comment: On Windows, at least, you can have 2 Command Prompt windows that operate independently.  That said, I do not understand why you have to have the script close the window instead of you closing it.  As you noticed, IDLE is designed to not let scripts close it.  When you run code from the editor or with `-r myfile.py` on startup, it emulates running the code with `python -i myfile.py`. In that mode, `raise SystemExit`, for instance, in myfile, results in an interactive `>>> ` prompt.